# Stop the music app to play music

Tags: android

I've searched around but haven't found any answers. I want my app, if there is music app playing music (e.g Google Music), stop the playing music from my app. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on audio player being used. You may be able to control some, but other may remain immune.  With built-in one, you can try this code

```
public static final String SERVICECMD = "com.android.music.musicservicecommand";
public static final String CMDNAME = "command";
public static final String CMDSTOP = "stop";

AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

if(mAudioManager.isMusicActive()) {
    Intent i = new Intent(SERVICECMD);
    i.putExtra(CMDNAME , CMDSTOP );
    YourApplicationClass.this.sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

other commands are

```
public static final String CMDTOGGLEPAUSE = "togglepause";
public static final String CMDPAUSE = "pause";
public static final String CMDPREVIOUS = "previous";
public static final String CMDNEXT = "next";
```

Commands are taken from [android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/1.5_r4/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java)

Comment: Works for me, able to stop google music play with it. thx

Comment: @Karoly: Do you find any solution to stop/exit google music? I also met the issue